# Which is more conventional function name between "ContainsElement" and "DoesContainElement"?

Tags: c++, function, coding-style, maintainability

I'm writing a function to determine whether an element exists in a container. I don't know how to choose the function name between:

`bool ContainerType::ContainsElement(const ElementType& elem);`

and

`bool ContainerType::DoesContainElement(const ElementType& elem);`

Consider the following two scenario:

Version 1:

```
ContainerType coll;
ElementType   elem;
...

if (coll.ContainsElement(elem))
{
    cout << elem << " exists." << endl;
}
```

Version 2:

```
ContainerType coll;
ElementType   elem;
...

if (coll.DoesContainElement(elem))
{
    cout << elem << " exists." << endl;
}
```

As I understand it, I think version 1 is more like natural English. However, I also found version 2's style is used more widely.

What's your opinion?

**Update:**

```
FltIsOperationSynchronous
FltIsIoCanceled
FltIsVolumeWritable
```

The three function names above are excerpted from Microsft's documentation. If the prefix "Flt" are stripped, they are:

```
IsOperationSynchronous
IsIoCanceled
IsVolumeWritable
```

rather than

```
OperationIsSynchronous
IoIsCanceled
VolumeIsWritable
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

`contains` is the most popular.  `containsElement` could be, and I've never seen `doesContainElement`.  Probably too long.

If you are trying to emulate English, think that `bool` functions are usually used with `if`.  What sounds better:

```
    if( a.containsElement(b) )

    if( a.doesContainElement(b) )

    if( a.contains(b) )
```

?  I think 3, then 1, then 2, don't you?

Comment: Please review my update. I think Microsoft and many other companies seem to like 2 more. why?

Comment: @xmllmx  One possible explanation is that by starting with an auxiliary verb (`is`, `does`, `has`, etc), it is clear that the function returns a `bool`.  `contains` is not very far from it, but 1) you wouldn't use it alone in an English question, and 2) you need to reach the end to notice it's a verb, which is much longer than `is`, `does`, or `has`.